# How can I exclude the conditions evaluation report from the console of a Spring boot application?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

When I run my Spring boot application, I get the conditions evaluation report in my console logs.

How can I disable or exclude this report from my console logs in Spring boot?

```
============================
CONDITIONS EVALUATION REPORT
============================


Positive matches:
-----------------

   AopAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy', 'org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect', 'org.aspectj.lang.reflect.Advice', 'org.aspectj.weaver.AnnotatedElement'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.aop.auto=true) matched (OnPropertyCondition)

   AopAutoConfiguration.CglibAutoProxyConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.aop.proxy-target-class=true) matched (OnPropertyCondition)

   CacheAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.cache.CacheManager'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'cacheInterceptor'; @ConditionalOnMissingBean (names: cacheResolver; types: org.springframework.cache.CacheManager; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

...
```

Answer (score 48):

You can do this by changing the log level of `org.springframework.boot.autconfigure`. For example by adding the following line within `application.properties`:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure=ERROR
```

Answer (score 38):

You'll get the condition outcome report if you:

- Configure your IDE to show debug output (for example, if you set **Enable debug output** within a Spring boot run configuration in IntelliJ).
- Set the property `debug=true` within application.properties.
- Set the logging level of `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging` to `DEBUG`.

This can be useful when you're trying to find out why certain beans are not being loaded, because with this report you can see exactly which autoconfiguration is being loaded, and which one isn't (and why).

You can disable this output by undoing the earlier mentioned bullet points. For example, you could set the logging level of `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging` to `INFO`:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging=INFO
```

Comment: ```Configure your IDE to show debug output (for example, if you set Enable debug output within a Spring boot run configuration in IntelliJ).
```

I did this., I dont know how to disable it. please help.

Answer (score 11):

While the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50273889) works, it's also possible to set the log level to `INFO`:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure=INFO
```

Answer (score 1):

just add to application.yml the following

```yaml
logging:
  level:
    ROOT: INFO
    you/package/path: INFO
```

Answer (score 1):

Also disable in "Run/Debug Configuration" -> Modify options -> "Enable debug Output"

[IntelliJ DebugConfigration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNlRb.png)

Comment: For me this was the only one to be working, the others I tried but didn't

Answer (score 0):

If you have application.yml the answer is

```
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.boot: ERROR
```